# MarkLogic ACID and scalability

Tags: marklogic

I am new to NoSQL and MarkLogic.
My understanding is that MarkLogic has a near-linear scalability with multi document ACID.

In the case of a READ, how does MarkLogic achieve near-linear scalability with a shared-nothing architecture?

In the case of an UPDATE against dozens of nodes/forests, I am guessing the lock will be a huge overhead.

How does MarkLogic handle the above problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [a blog post on isolation and how this works](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/i-is-for-isolation) a while ago.

The gist is that we do lock-free reads at an [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) timestamp, and we lock records during update transactions in ways similar to relational DBMS systems. For cross-partition transactions we use two-phase commit.

Locks don't in themselves impose huge overhead, but like any DBMS, you can run into locking issues if you're doing a lot of large concurrent updates that are not independent. We have monitoring for that and deadlock detection/resolution.

You can also use predicate locks ([see the blog post](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/i-is-for-isolation)) to mitigate if you're doing large updates and want to serialize concurrent transactions on the same domain to avoid deadlocks.